# PHP - Headers to download pdf file

Tags: php, pdf

i used this line of codes to download pdf file in different browsers. When i tried on desktop and android browsers, its okay, but when i tried Ipad, and iphone devices, the download doesn't happen. i dont know if there's error in this codes..

```
$local_file = $path;
            $download_file = $path;

            // set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)
            $download_rate = 100;
            if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file))
            {
                /*header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
                header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

                flush();
                readfile($local_file);*/


                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

                $file = $local_file;
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file_name));   
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Type: application/download");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
                header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
                flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
                $fp = fopen($file, "r");
                while (!feof($fp))
                {
                    echo fread($fp, 65536);
                    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
                } 
                fclose($fp); 


            }else {
                die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
            }
```

Comment: This code is mad chaos.

Answer (score 0):

First, the suggested name of the downloaded file should be enclosed in double-quotes, and the correct content-type set (required so that the right viewer could be opened on the client) :

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"{$filename}\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Then, don't bother reading the file within a loop, use :
    readfile($file);
    die();

By the way, in all my downloads, I also append the following headers (you may omit some of them depending of what you intend to do) :

```
// to force the client to save the file, not opening it inside the browser
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");

// disable caching on client and proxies, if the download content vary
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I suggest you to clear the headers part in your code and only use the first two ones above (don't use content-length at the moment).